# Which scope to use with vaadin and spring?

Tags: java, spring, session, vaadin, vaadin7

I'd like to develop a vaadin application with spring. A user should be able to login and see uer-specific pages. I he comes to the site from a different browser window, it would be handy if the user is still logged in, so preserves the session.

Now I wonder which scope to use for this purpose? Vaadin and Spring offer a `@Scope("session")`, `@Scope("ui")` and a `@Scope("prototype")`. Should I just place all of my *View and *Presenter classes in the `session` scope?

Or would it be better to have the view annoted with `prototype`, so that each time a pages is changed the page is recreated with updated data?
In this case, should then the presenters be still session scope, or also prototye?

Or should I at all use the `ui` scope that's provided by `vaadin4spring` boot addon? This would then create a new "uiSession" for every new tab.

```
@Scope("session")
class MyPresenter {
    //each view should be wired to a presenter
    @Autowired
    private MyView view;
}

@Scope("prototype") //"session", "ui"?
class MyView extends VerticalLayout {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        addComponent(new Label("time is: " + new Date()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using [vaadin4spring](https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring)?

Comment: yes, vaadin4spring offers the `ui` scope, as written above. And I wonder which to prefer: ui or session scope

Comment: I think you mix what Vaadin and Spring are doing. If you are logged in, those information are kept in the session (i.e. Spring's session scope). So I am not sure I understand what the problem would be. If you want to share the same view within different tabs, it's a different story but security is kind of unrelated to the problem.

Comment: I'm just concerned, from the design point of view, which scope my View and Presenter classes should get. Eg, if it is right to give the views the prototype, and the presenter the session scope.

Comment: vaadin stores (large amounts) of state in the session.  state is pretty much anything, that is visible to the client in the browser.  the ui scope is what you should use if any component is involved.  even if ui and session seem the same, you should stick to ui, as we as mere users of the framework might not know or understand each implementation detail of vaadin and subtle errors might creep in when using the session directly.  or think like this: if there where no need for a ui scope, then they would have not added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vaadin stores (large amounts of) state in the session. state is pretty much anything, that is visible to the client in the browser. the ui scope is what you should use, if any component is involved. even if ui and session seem the same, you should stick to ui to prevent raceconditions and worse against the vaadin code.

in your example above, view is definetly ui, because it is a component.  this makes the presenter ui also as it holds reference to an ui scoped component and will for sure tap into events from it or read data etc.